# The homomorphic image of an abelian group is abelian . How to prove its converse is not true.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be an Abelian group and elements a,b belong to G 
Then f(a)f(b)=f(ab) as f is homomorphic 
F(ab)=f(ba)=f(b)f(a) so we can say G is abelian

But how do I prove its converse is not true, should I take an example of an abelian group and show it is not homomorphic?Is that sufficient

Comment: You have to show that there is a homomorphism $f : G \to H$ with $G$ non-abelian but $f(G)$ abelian.

Comment: What does it mean to show a group is not homomorphic? Do you understand the result you're trying to disprove the converse of?

Comment: @ Matt Samuel , don't you mean "What does it mean to show in particular that an ABELIAN group is not homomorphic ? " of course I understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Given any group $G$, we can form the quotient group $G^{\rm ab}=G/[G,G]$ where $[G,G]$ is the subgroup generated by commutators $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. This quotient is abelian, and it is called the abelianization of $G$. This shows every group admits an abelian homomorphic image, and in fact this map is functorial from groups to abelian groups and left adjoint to the inclusion functor of abelian groups into groups. That is, for each group $G$ and abelian group $A$ there is a bijection $\eta_{G,A}$ between group morphisms $G\to A$ and abelian group morphisms $G^{\rm ab}\to A$ that is natural in both variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The trivial group is a homomorphic image of *everything*.

---

Alternative hint: What can you say about the direct product of an abelian group with a non-abelian group?

Comment: Sir in the first part of your hint should it work? Because shouldn't  the proof of "Every homomorphic image of an abelian group is abelian " hold only provided it is an epimorphism? But you hint indicates an into homomorphism. Please correct me if I am wrong.